# ExpandableListView onChildClick how to get information which part of view was clicked

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have problem with getting information which part of view has been clicked.
I have child row item defined as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
  android:id="@+id/child_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/row_height"
        android:background="@color/app_white" >


        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/row_margin"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_states"
            android:focusable="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:focusable="false"  />   

</LinearLayout>
```

and in Activity I need to define onChildClick

```
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
            int childPosition, long id) {
Log.e(LOGTAG, "onChildClick: v.getTag: " + v.getTag() + " groupPos: " + groupPosition
                + " childPosition: " + childPosition + " rowId: " + id);

        if (v instanceof LinearLayout) {
            View view = ((LinearLayout) v).getChildAt(1);
            if (view != null) {
                if (view.getTag() != null) {
                    Log.e(LOGTAG, "onChildClick: view.isSelected: "+view.isSelected());
                    Log.e(LOGTAG, "onChildClick: view.isPressed: "+view.isPressed());
                    Log.e(LOGTAG, "onChildClick: view.getTag: " + view.getTag());
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
```

and as I can see the view is always LinearLayout. How can I get information if view or RelativeLayout is clicked?

Comment: You have to set listeners for those views if you want to capture individual clicks on them.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621070/get-context-of-popupmenu-like-contextmenu

Answer (score 0):

onChildClick() will always return the whole child row that was clicked. if you want to know if the RelativeLayout was clicked, then you need to add an onCLickListener to that one.